# Script that checks youtube for new videos

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, youtube

Im wondering if there is a way to check a specific youtube channel and create a list of links out of the videos on that channel.

Im not so worried about the list making part as i am with getting the link information.

Also if there is a way, would it update when there is a new post to that channel?

I'm guessing out of php and js, JS is the better choice for this. If there is a jQuery solution that would be even more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The YouTube API offers channel specific RSS/JSON feeds which a php script could read out and digest. Feeds are usually accessed via

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/CHANNELNAME/uploads?orderby=updated

Check out the API documentation for more info http://gdata.youtube.com/

Comment: do u know if there is an option to have a screenshot of the video for each item in the feed. so far i've come up with this URI: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?orderby=published&author=CHANNELNAME

Comment: im not to familiar with XML but after reading it i saw this. <media:thumbnail url='http://i.ytimg.com/vi/mc8C9wfd1Rw/1.jpg' height='90' width='120' time='00:00:15.750' yt:name='start'/> which looks like a thumbnail. Im going to run it through a JS parser and see what i can do.

Comment: This url suggested is not available anymore
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/